# Speed Optimization in J2EE Application, Client side?

Tags: java, javascript, css, jakarta-ee

Currently i am working on speed optimization of J2EE Application. The **performance of the application** is currently(*in my case server is running pretty fast*) **more depended on the amount of time that it takes to download the associated files** like js, css etc.

> My Question:
>
> Is there any way to compress these files(js, css,
>   images etc..) and send it to client machine?

I have came through some technologies which **compress the js into a single line**, but its **causing some problems with the current syntax**.

> I like to know some way to compress and sent the files, if possible, for best client-side performance.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: My question is how to compress js, css ect and sent that to client mechine..??

Comment: Then remove the parts asking for tool suggestions, because those parts are off-topic. In addition, some people might like more detail about the "causing some problems with the current syntax"

Comment: Consider https://developers.google.com/speed/ to start. There are tools to test your site, web server plugin to automatically apply optimizations, but *more importantly* there are details on best practices.

Comment: @user113215 okie let me check.

Comment: There are content delivery networks and reverse proxies. What is your actual objective here? One common technique is to serve the static content from a discrete server (or pool of servers). And then there are data compression tools, like serving the content gzip-ed.

Comment: My Js file size is increasing day by day. As the requirements increases, its getting more bigger. So i need to find a way to minimise the time to download this files. Currently there are multiple js files. which cause the issue.

Comment: @Dileep are you using javascript minifiers?

Comment: @RafaelOsipov No its causing issue when compressing certain script.! It really need to have a good standard format to compress. like semicollon etc. So minifier is not the best option

Answer (score 0):

There is basically Two way to achive this functionality are as below

1) minify your css and js with minfy tool which avilable online.

I use Google Closure Tools, it uses Rhino to interpret your code while modifying it to enusre that it still works after minification. Many free tools exists: YUI Compressor, UglifyJS, etc.

UglifyJS is also good as well, try it here http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs

Google Closure Tools: https://developers.google.com/closure/

2) Gzip your css and js.Do server specific configuration to use Gzip

here i have link from where you can learn how GZip work

http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/

Comment: The second option seems interesting. Will update you after i go through it .

Comment: @Dileep : go through it,it will sure help you to achive your functionality